# How to check if a 'any'-Object fits a union type?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

I'm getting an object (type: any) of an external library A and want to pass it to a function from a library B. That function expects a Type B-Input, which is a Union Type (number | string | somethingCustom).
How can I check if the object is compatible?

(More precise: momentJS expects a MomentInput. An Angular AbstractControl.value has type any. I am looking for a type safe way to handle this to be sure that the passed value matches the functions expectations and throw an error otherwise.)

Code Example:

```
someFunction(obj: any): Moment {
// Sadly, it is unchecked wheter obj fits the input type for moment()
// Linter is unhappy (no-unsafe-argument), disabling linter is unsatisfying
    return moment(obj)
}
```

Comment: You may want to look at [type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html)

Comment: @OliverRadini I read about that but problem is: It is out of my control and knowledge which functions and values Library B (MomentJS) actually needs.

Comment: I think then that this may need some code examples of what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: This isn't something you can fix with static analysis (at least, not the way you've described it). The arg object that you get from a third party that is type `any` that you then hand off to another third party (momentjs) and you don't know if `moment` will throw or return an invalid value? Yeah, you can't fix that without a better typed value that you get from the other library... or by doing runtime checks. You're probably better off just wrapping it in a `try/catch` and ignoring that line for linting.

Comment: @JaredSmith Hmmm, I feared so. I hoped it would be possible to check against the well defined MomentInput interface whose purpose is to define what values are okay. But now that you are saying it, I wouldn't even know how to check if an any object is a number, so how could I check against a Union Type...
How would I do if I knew that obj was a string?

Comment: No no no. That's not what I'm saying at all. It's easy enough to check if a value conforms to a given type. But you will have to write a bunch of **runtime** checks and make an *assertion* to the compiler via a type guard, and you will have to do that for every possible valid value (IIRC the moment function is pretty lenient with what it accepts). I'm saying it's probably not worth it. You won't be any safer than if you just use `try/catch` because the compiler won't be able to warn you. You can write 50 LoC to play at security theatre, or you can just handle the error. Your call.

Comment: I see. Exactly what I was fearing. Im just kinda surprised that altough there is a well defined interface, you can't really check against it without so much hustle...
Would have expected something along the lines of "if (x is MomentInput)".

Comment: @fortuneNext - MomentJS's interface is thoroughly explained, but I wouldn't call it "well defined." It's very loose. :-) You'll probably want to use `m.isValid()` to check the resulting Moment object you get from `moment()` to see if it was able to understand what you gave it as an input, even if the input is a string (one of the types it documents it can understand). For instance, `moment("-")` produces a Moment object where `isValid()` is false (its underlying time number is `NaN`, meaning it has no idea what date/time it is). :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder For future reference: How would such a library give a clean interface I can check against? I would have thought that "Give me a | b | c" would be suffitient, but apparently it's not...

Comment: @fortuneNext - It would be, if Moment actually did limit its inputs in that way (and if `MomentInputObject` didn't consist entirely of optional properties), but it doesn't. If you give it something it doesn't actually accept (a `Map`, for instance, or a `Set`, or a `Symbol`), it just tries to convert that to string and proceed with the string rather than complaining about having been given something it doesn't support. That would be one thing I'd change if I were writing a lib of that sort. :-) Happy coding!

Comment: To be clear: I'm not giving MomentJS a hard time. It was written in a very JavaScript-y way back in the day, before TypeScript even existed. Fair enough it isn't written with type safety in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MomentJS is a bit of a special case, because although the types do give a list of what it will accept, it will actually accept just about anything. If what it gets isn't one of the things it expects, it converts it to string (implicitly). The result in cases where you give it something it doesn't support is a Moment instance with `NaN` as the time value (you can use `isValid()` to find out if the Momen tinstance has a valid time value). More on that below.

Addressing the general question, though: Unfortunately, you can only do this for the types you know to test for, you can't *discover* the types used by MomentJS in its `MomentInput` type and generate tests at runtime to check for them.

At present, the `MomentInput` type is:

```typescript
type MomentInput = Moment | Date | string | number | (number | string)[] | MomentInputObject | null | undefined;
```

You could write a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to test whether a given value is one of the types in that union. Sadly, this is complicated a bit by the fact that one of the above is `MomentInputObject`, which is an object type where **all 24 properties** are optional. So `{}` is a valid `MomentInputObject`, and so basically anything goes.

But let's try it anyway:

```typescript
// PLEASE NOTE: This is untested and may need tweaking. It's not meant to
// be perfect from the get-go, it's meant to demonstrate the kind of
// function _you'd_ write to do this.

import moment, { isMoment, MomentInput, MomentInputObject } from "moment";

function isMomentInput(value: any): value is MomentInput {
    switch (typeof value) {
        case "string":
        case "number":
        case "undefined":
            return true;
        case "object":
            if (value instanceof Date) {
                return true;
            }
            if (Array.isArray(value)) {
                return value.every((element) => {
                    const elementType = typeof element;
                    return elementType === "string" || elementType === "number";
                });
            }
            return (
                value === null || isMoment(moment) || isMomentInputObject(value)
            );
    }
    return false;
}

const momentInputObjectPropNames = [
    "years",
    "year",
    "y",

    "months",
    "month",
    "M",

    "days",
    "day",
    "d",

    "dates",
    "date",
    "D",

    "hours",
    "hour",
    "h",

    "minutes",
    "minute",
    "m",

    "seconds",
    "second",
    "s",

    "milliseconds",
    "millisecond",
    "ms",
];

function isMomentInputObject(value: any): value is MomentInputObject {
    // Note: This requires at least one of the named properties.
    // Technically, from TypeScript's point of view, that's incorrect,
    // `MomentInputObject` allows `{}` because it has no required properties.
    // Pragmatically, though, it's probably what you want.
    return momentInputObjectPropNames.some((propName) => propName in value);
}
```

Then your code is:

```
someFunction(obj: any): Moment {
    if (!isMomentInput(obj)) {
        // throw new Error(`Invalid Moment input`);
        // (Or return something)
    }
    return moment(obj);
}
```

Note that the `isMomentInput` function will need updating if MomentJS changes `MomentInput`. MomentJS is in maintenance mode so that's probably not an issue, but still...

**Note:** You'll still want to allow for the possibility the `moment` call throws an error¹ or returns a moment instance whose underlying time value is `NaN` because it couldn't figure out what to use (which it does in many cases). For instance, `moment("-")` returns a Moment object with `NaN` as its time value (which converts to "Invalid Date" if you convert it to string). For instance, your usage code might do:

```
someFunction(obj: any): Moment {
    if (!isMomentInput(obj)) {
        // throw new Error(`Invalid Moment input`);
        // (Or return something)
    }
    const m = moment(obj);
    if (!m.isValid()) {
        // throw new Error(`Invalid Moment input`);
        // (Or return something)
    }
    return m;
}
```

---

¹ Re `moment` throwing an error: I'm not aware of a case where `moment`, itself, throws an error. But if you passed it a `Symbol`, *that* would throw because `moment` tries to implicitly convert that to a string, which Symbols disallows. The same would be true of any object that throws when its `toString` method is called.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript just provides type annotations at compile type, for this reason you need some way to distinguish a compatible type by a not compatible one programmatically.

You can use a type guard:

```
isCompatible(x: any): x is string|number|somethingCustom {
  // your logic
  // return true / false;
}
```

Note that for primitive types, like string or numbers, custom type guards are superfluous since you can use a `typeof` type guard (`if (typeof x === 'number')`)

Otherwise, if you trust your source and you know in advance that the type will be compatible, or for some reason you don't want perform any check, you can use a type assertion:

```
const obj: any;
fn(obj as string); // supposing that fn accepts a parameter of type string|number|somethingCustom
```

Comment: Sadly it is out of my control and knowledge which functions and values Library B (MomentJS) actually needs, so hard to write custom logic for this.

Comment: @fortuneNext MomentJs will not change. Ever. It would break the internet. So you can make a very educated guess if the input will actually work (and you actually should imo) - e.g. if its a string the moment constructor can actually parse. Blindly ignoring errors can lead to very frustrating user experience and in this particular case seems easy to handle. Check the docs for valid input formats / types: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @Loop  I see. Hypothetically, how would a similar library need to provide it's interface so that I can make a clean check?

Comment: That's a tough one to answer. In the case of moment I don't see any way around handing through responsibility to the developer since there is such a high number of possibilities how to enter a date.

Comment: Since there is no checked exception or similar concept (which has its own drawbacks) in Typescript, the only other option I see is very good documentation which kind of errors the library method could throw and maybe a validator / helper function of some kind. Another concept, which I tried and found very cumbersome is the Tried<SUCCESS, ERROR> pattern as described in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13219.  In theory, the pattern is very explicit and forces the developer to do the right thing, on the other hand the code gets extremely bloated with ifs and elses.